# Ubuntu phone - clock on welcome screen showing wrong time

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, time

I have Ubuntu phone Aquaris BQ 4.5 UE (with latest available updates) and I think the phone uses two dfferent times - different times for different applications.

1) UTC (which is not my local time) is used:

1a) by the clock on the welcome screen

1b) by the clock in the notification bar (top of the screen)

1c) probably by the alarm clock funtion which is set via application "Clock". But the "Clock" itself is showing the correct local time. Alarm won't ring when it is supposed to ring but accoridng to some strange rules. I think it must be set good time ahead and then if it rings, then it is only according to UTC. This is really disturbing as in my case it would be one or two hours too late :-).

2) My correct local time (UTC+2 in summer or UTC+1 in winter) I get:

2a) in Terminal (using the command date).

2b) in "System settings" --> "Time & Date" --> "Set the time and date" which is set to "Automatically" and one line below it is showing the correct local time.

2c) Application "Clock" is showing also the correct local time.

2d) Application "Calendar" is using it probably as well as all entries in the "Calendar" trigger an alarm sound at the right (local) time.

DST change a few days ago worked in cases 2a-2d fine as well but didn't influence any of the 1a-1c. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: What timezone did you define under "Time & Date" in "System settings"? Not sure, but maybe it makes a difference?

Comment: @Bruni your suggestion is much appreciated. In "System settings" --> "Time & Date" I have two fields which look like I could edit them. The upper one is "Time zone:" and the value is "UTC+1" (correct one). I have no control over this. Whatever city I choose in its sub-menu, the value still stays "UTC+1" and the choice is forgotten. The lower filed is "Set the time and date" with options "Automatically" or "Manually". If I manually change the time to e.g. 00:30 the time at the notification bar immediately changes to 23:30. Even if I have this option at "Manually" I can't change the time zone.

Comment: It is indeed strange that you cannot change that setting...it is possible on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

The ntp service is probably running and using the port try the following from terminal and let me know if it worked

```
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
sudo service ntp start
```

Comment: Thank you RiaanV, but it does not seem the ntp is running. After typing "sudo service ntp stop" I got "ntp: unrecognized service". Then I tried "sudo service --status-all" to get a list of services, there are approx. 50 services listed but ntp is not among them. Then I also try to switch it on "sudo service ntp start" but it was again "ntp: unrecognized service". But I could run sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov (also with ntp.ubuntu.com). I tried that both in normal and developer mode. I reset the phone to factory sesttings a few weeks ago. No change.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is solved. I followed this guide to flash Aquaris Ubuntu E4.5 to Android and then I flashed it back to Ubuntu (some older image mentioned in the guide and then OTA update): http://a25.co/ubuntu-phone-how-to-install-android. Now I have just one time zone and the alarm clock works.

Small note about the hardware. I can agree with the author of the guide. The phone itself is a very decent piece of hardware (when running Android), Ubuntu is lagging a lot, but from the optimistic point of view, there is a lot of potential :-)